# React: Dropdown not closing on tap outside

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following code I am using to create a dropdown list for some items:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connectRefinementList } from "react-instantsearch-dom"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

const cx = label => `ais-DropdownRefinementList-${label}`

class DropdownRefinementList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      active: false,
      mobile: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      mobile: /Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent),
    })
  }
  capitalizeFirst(s) {
    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
  }
  renderItem = (item, i) => (
    <label key={i} className="ais-DropdownRefinementList-item-label">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={item.isRefined}
        onChange={() => {
          this.selectItem(item)
        }}
      />
      <span>{item.label}</span>
      <span className={cx("item-count")}> ({item.count})</span>
    </label>
  )
  selectItem = (item, resetQuery) => {
    this.props.refine(item.value)
  }
  handleEvent = e => {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })
  }
  render() {
    const { items, attribute, hoverable, currentRefinement, icon } = this.props
    const { active, mobile } = this.state
    const title = this.capitalizeFirst(attribute)
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div
        className={`ais-DropdownRefinementList-container-${attribute}`}
        onMouseLeave={hoverable && !mobile && this.handleEvent}
        onMouseEnter={hoverable && !mobile && this.handleEvent}
      >
        <div className={cx("title-container")} onClick={this.handleEvent}>
          <span class="w-full focus:text-teal-500 hover:text-teal-500 justify-center inline-block text-gray-600 text-xl text-center ">
            {icon}
          </span>
          <span className="ais-DropdownRefinementList-title font-bold w-full text-gray-600">
            {title}{" "}
          </span>
        </div>
        {active && (
          <div className={`ais-DropdownRefinementList-List ${attribute}`}>
            {items.map(this.renderItem)}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

DropdownRefinementList.propTypes = {
  attribute: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  hoverable: PropTypes.bool,
  limit: PropTypes.number,
}
DropdownRefinementList.defaultProps = {
  hoverable: false,
}

export default connectRefinementList(DropdownRefinementList)
```

On a laptop these work fine, and when I hover my mouse over the list title, the dropdown opens and when I leave, the dropdown closes. I had assumed that the same would happen when I was on mobile. However, this is not the case. One dropdown will remain open while the user clicks another. This is demonstrated below:

[image]

This is despite having this the conditions for `onMouseLeave` and `onMouseEnter`. Is this not applicable to mobile devices? Shouldn't a tap outside the container hide it again, like it should?

How can I make this work for mobiles too?

If it helps, [this is the CSS for this component](https://gist.github.com/thedivtagguy/f25bbd8e502df159c250f84b3ee91579) and [here](https://srishtiarchive.com) is a live deploy (you'll have to switch to mobile view with Inspect Element, as it is hidden on big screens).

Answer (score 1):

I looked at some documentation for how mouse events are translated on mobile: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent

My suggestion is not to rely on mouseenter and mouseleave on mobile. I would make active a prop and let the parent keep track of which DropdownRefinementLists should be visible. That's because DropdownRefinementList can't see click events that are outside. I'd handle the "outside click" event in the ancestor that receives events for the external space.

Example code:

This is the (new) `DropdownRefinementList`. `this.props.active` is true or false, depending on whether it should be displaying the popup. It invokes `this.props.setActive()` when it receives a click/touch.

```
class DropdownRefinementList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  handleEvent = e => {
    this.props.setActive();
    e.stopPropagation(); //stop event from propagating to ancestor elements
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleEvent} style={{position: 'relative', padding: '5px'}}>
        <h3>
            {this.props.title}
        </h3>
        <div style={{marginTop: '1rem'}}>
          Click me!
        </div>
        {this.props.active && (
          <div style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '-50px', left: '25px',
                height: '150px', width: '200px',
                borderStyle: 'solid',
                backgroundColor: '#ccc',
                padding: '5px',
                zIndex: 100
                }}>
            {this.props.title}{' '} Popup
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the parent component. `this.state.activeDropdown` takes the following 3 values:

- 0: No Dropdown is active
- 1: Dropdown 1 is active
- 2: Dropdown 2 is active

It sets `this.state.activeDropdown` to 0 when it receives a click/touch.

```
class DropdownRefinementListParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        activeDropdown: 0
    }
  }
  
  setActive = (whichDropdown) => {
    this.setState({activeDropdown: whichDropdown});
  }
  handleEvent = (e, whichDropdown) => {
    
    this.setActive(0);
    e.stopPropagation(); //stop event from propagating to ancestor elements
  }  
  render() {
    const dropdown1IsActive = (this.state.activeDropdown === 1);
    const dropdown2IsActive = (this.state.activeDropdown === 2);
  
    return (
        <div onClick={e => this.handleEvent(e, 0)}>
      
        <h2>DropdownRefinementList Parent</h2>
      
        <div>activeDropdown: {this.state.activeDropdown}</div>
      
        <div style={{display: 'flex', margin: '10px 0', width: '600px', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
        
          <div style={{flexGrow: 0, borderStyle: 'solid', margin: '5px'}}>
            <DropdownRefinementList
                title="DropdownRefinementList 1"
                active={dropdown1IsActive}
                setActive={() => this.setActive(1)} />
          </div>
          
          <div style={{flexGrow: 0, borderStyle: 'solid', margin: '5px'}}>
            <DropdownRefinementList
                title="DropdownRefinementList 2"
                active={dropdown2IsActive}
                setActive={() => this.setActive(2)} />
          </div>
        </div>
        end
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Live demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzcwL64a/5/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your suggestion! Would you be able to share some code as well? I'm not sure how to make this work and a basic example based on my context would be great.